# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " " in postgres while converting to CSV

Tags: postgresql

We are getting below error while converting the data fie to CSV and writing the data from CSV to table.

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "

There is column with data type numeric while converting to CSV it is extracted as empty and same while inserting to table for the datatype numeric it is not allowing.

How to convert the numeric data type and conver the data to null.?

I need command how to convert the numeric data type column value empty string to Null while inserting into table.?

Comment: That doesn't look empty, it looks like a single space.

Comment: This needs more information. **Add as update to question**:1) Show code for  'converting the data fie to CSV'? 2) Show the code you are using to '... writing the data from CSV to table.`